# Generalized Pell equation $ x^2 - (k^2-1)y^2 = p $ and solutions recurrence relations

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Solving the Pell equation $ x^2 - (k^2-1)y^2 = 1 $, the general solutions for $y$ are generated by the recurrence relation

$y_{n+2} = 2k\cdot y_{n+1} - y_n, y_0 = 0, y_1 = 1$

which is the same of the [Chebyshev Polynomial of the Second Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) and so the $n$th-solution for $y$ is $y= U_{n}(k) $

Now if if we generalize the equation to $ x^2 - (k^2-1)y^2 = p $, with $p$ an odd prime, it's possible to say, using the Binary Quadratic Forms theory, that if the Legendre symbol $(\frac{k^2-1}{p}) = 1$ then one between $ x^2 - (k^2-1)y^2 = p $ and $(k^2-1)y^2 -x^2 = p $  has solutions (infinitely many), while the other have none.

Finding the first few solutions for $ k=2,3,4$ I noticed that this time the general solutions for $y$ are generated by the new recurrence relation

$y_{n} = 2k\cdot y_{n-2} - y_{n-4}$

Why this change happen? Is it still possible to use the Chebyshev Polynomials to find the $n$th-solution?

Comment: well, no. Try to find $x^2 - 24 y^2 = 5$  or $x^2 - 24 y^2 = -5$

Answer (score 1):

for your $k=4,$   try prime $p=7$   You are trying to represent either $7 = x^2 - 15 y^2$ or $-7 = x^2 - 15 y^2.$   Also, Legendre symbol
$$   (15|7) = (1|7) = 1  $$

For $k = 2,3$  you really do get just one  $\pm$ pair of genera  and your idea works. For larger $k,$  there
forms other than plus or minus the principal form, and represented primes not represented by $\pm$  the principal form

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had to try with more values of k. Thank you even because I ever learned alot by your answers, expecially on Diophantine equations. If we restrict to $k=2,3$ why the solutions follow that recurrence?